# Check which of two where statements has been used

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using this code

```
SqlCommand cmd = 
  new SqlCommand(select * from customers where phone = @mobile1 or phone = @mobile2), con);
```

How can I check which of two conditions in the `WHERE` clause applies in my case?

Example has `mobile1` or `mobile2` be used to select a row?

Is there any way to check this?

Answer (score 5):

You could add an extra column:

```
select *,
  CASE WHEN phone=@mobile1 THEN 1
       WHEN phone=@mobile2 THEN 2
  END as PhoneUsed
from customers
where phone=@mobile1 or phone=@mobile2
```

This will favour `@mobile1` if the two happen to have identical values.

Comment: I think this is the answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Dim1 if this is the correct answer, please mark it as such ;)

Comment: Or you could add 2 columns instead and then you would know if it used first, second or both

Comment: "both" state will only be possible if "mobile1" equals "mobile2" ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can look into SQL Profiler to check what query is fired, or you can go to SSMS and use this query.

Also you can use an in clause, for example :

```
select * from customers where phone in ('A','B')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, case when phone = @mobile1 then 1 else 2 end as whichOne
from customers 
where phone in(@mobile1, @mobile2)
```